# How can I get the new value of an input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

So I have these two input fields written in html:

```
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="doc name" class="form-control " id="doc-name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="doc number" class="form-control " id="doc-number">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have some jquery code that returns me an error if either of the input fields remain empty:

```
if($('#doc-name').val() == '' || $('#doc-number').val =='')  {
    return false //this is completed with the actual error script but isn't important to the current issue
}
```

The issue that I actually have is that even after I complete the input fields, the .val() command still return an empty string, it is not returning what I actually wrote in those inputs. .html() or .text() also return something empty. Can you please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: I don't know if that's your problem, but you're missing a `'` in the first selector (`$(#doc-name')` should be `$('#doc-name')`) and a couple of parentheses and id selector on the second (`$('doc-number').val` should be `$('#doc-number').val()`).

Comment: `'doc-number'` is also not a valid selector. Presumably you mean `#doc-number` instead. I'd strongly suggest you check the console when you're debugging JS code.

Comment: When do you call your "if(...){}" ?

Comment: I wrote that in a hurry, the selectors are written as you say, correctly, but the $('doc-name').val() string is still empty even after I complete the input with some text.

Comment: The key here is how you are calling your if statement. What is triggering your script to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean. But I've created a sample here where every click event it will get the value of the input fields.

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="number"/>
<button id="getvalue">Get value</button>
```

Here's the js

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$('#getvalue').click( function() {

    var nameVal = $('#name').val();
    var numVal = $('#number').val();

    if(nameVal == '' || numVal == ''){
        alert('Empty fields.')
    }else{
        alert('Name is ' + nameVal + ' and Number is ' + numVal);
    }

});
});
```

You need to have a trigger event in order for javascript to communicate with your html elements. In this case we are using a click event through button element.

Here's a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfHZV/1847/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `'#doc-name'` and `'#doc-number'`:

```js
if ($('#doc-name').val() == '' || $('#doc-number').val() == '') {
  alert('Error');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc name" class="form-control " id="doc-name">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <label>Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc number" class="form-control " id="doc-number">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I wrote that in a hurry, they are as you say, but the value still does not change, it just gets the original value from the html.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where/when you are calling that piece of code. In the example below it will execute on pressing a submit button.

https://jsfiddle.net/wy8z7b2k/

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  if ($('#doc-name').val() == '' || $('#doc-number').val() == '') {
    console.log('returning false');
    return false //this is completed with the actual error script but isn't important to the current issue
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc name" class="form-control " id="doc-name">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <label>Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc number" class="form-control " id="doc-number">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return false from an event handler it prevents the default action for that event and stops the event bubbling up through the DOM. That is, it is the equivalent of doing this:

```js
if($('#doc-name').val() == '' || $('doc-number').val == '')  {
alert('ok');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="doc name" class="form-control " id="doc-name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="doc number" class="form-control " id="doc-number">
    </div>
</div>
```